# How should data in xlsx format be indexed in Solr?

Tags: indexing, solr, xlsx

I have been tasked with uploading some data into Solr, whereupon it will be used for analysis.

I understand that Solr can index data in xlsx file formats.

In Exercise 2 for Solr, the following files were indexed in the order of json, xml and csv:

```
bin/post -c films example/films/films.json

bin/post -c films example/films/films.xml

bin/post -c films example/films/films.csv -params "f.genre.split=true&f.directed_by.split=true&f.genre.separator=|&f.directed_by.separator=|"
```

The issue I have is that the though I indexed my xlsx file, it only shows one record in the query, which means that the file may have been indexed wrongly, ie it may require parameters such as that needed by a csv file. Can anyone tell me how this indexing can be done without having to convert the xlsx file into a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apacha Tika  to index these formats in SOLR. It will parse the data and do the index.

Reference Link :
 https://lucidworks.com/2009/09/02/content-extraction-with-tika/

Comment: Thanks Pradeepan and MatsLindh. I have not tried Apache Tika, but I am grateful for yyour refernce. However, I am looking to directly index the xlsx file by way of using bin/post. Could anyone tell me how this should me done? I understand that Hortonworks may not have provided the such documentation pertinent to my question, though I am hoping that someone may have discovered how it may be done without the need for an intermediary such as Tika.

Comment: Tipo33 - Then you can use MultiPart form for uploading Excel files.

Comment: Thanks Pradeepan. I am not familiar with this form. Could you show me an example? Would this affect the indexing?